# Chrome: how to query multiple search engines from the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome, I've set up search keywords so that I can search directly from the address bar.  But this only works for a single site, like Google or Bing, etc.  Is there some way to enter a search term in the URL bar and have it search two or multiple engines and have the results from each search engine displayed in their own tab?

I'm guessing bookmarklet or extension may be necessary for this?

Comment: There's sites that do the multi-engine querying for you. Should have accelerators/search-plugins for those.

Comment: I also need to search sites on my company's intranet, so external multi-engine sites aren't sufficient.